# Consume various feed formats via a library (C# or PHP)?

Tags: c#, php, jquery, rss, atom-feed

I am looking for a library in either C# or PHP to consume various kinds of feeds such as RSS, Atom, eBay, Amazon, YouTube, Flickr, Twitter, Yelp, etc so I can standardize them under a single format to render under a single interface. Does anything like this exist?

There is something similar called WP Robot that is close (http://wprobot.net/modules/), but I do not want to depend on WordPress. Instead I want to consume through a C# or PHP middle layer and render thru jQuery.

Any ideas or experience would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [SimplePie](https://github.com/simplepie/simplepie) or [Zend_Feed_Reader](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.feed.reader.html), they both have support for almos every feed format out there.

Answer (score 2):

I think something like this would be difficult to find such libraries because there are so many services/feeds out there.

There is http://sharpbox.codeplex.com/ but that covers a **specific** area, cloud **storage**

I did stumble on to an interesting article though:
[C# and VB .NET Libraries to Digg, Flickr, Facebook, YouTube, Twitter, Live Services, Google and other Web 2.0 APIs](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheWeeklySourceCode22CAndVBNETLibrariesToDiggFlickrFacebookYouTubeTwitterLiveServicesGoogleAndOtherWeb20APIs.aspx)

I think you could just create your own mega library by reusing all existing lirbaries for specific services out there.